# Safari: Any way to initiate pinch-to-zoom without trackpad?

Tags: safari

Command + (Zoom in) and Command - (Zoom out) are different from pinch-to-zoom on a trackpad. The former changes the layout of the page, whereas the latter just enlarges the page as if a magnifier was used.

Is there any way to initiate pinch-to-zoom without a trackpad? Any methods such as a keyboard shortcut or an API.

Comment: If you looking for an API, Apple has the trackpad API here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html

Comment: I am not familiar with OS X programming, but on Windows, you can simulate mouse movements by sending the events to the application using `SendMessage()` or `PostMessage()`. Is such thing possible with OS X? I want to send the some kind of  'pinch-to-zoom occurred' event to Safari.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this is a proper solution since it involves Logi Option app (for setting up Logitech wired/wireless keyboards and mice). But it works for me with my MX Master 2S mouse.

I found out that the Zoom function in Logi Option app does the same thing as a pinch zoom on trackpad. It's vector kind of zoom - not pixelated like bitmap zoom. I've assigned my Gesture Button for "Zoom using scroll wheel" (hold down Gesture Button and scroll up/down for zooming in/out).

There is also a quicker Smart Zoom option for one-click, one-level zoom.

[image: Logi Option Zoom mimics pinch zoom on trackpad]

Answer (score 2):

I am using *Apple Magic Mouse*.

In Settings > Mouse > Point & Click,
there's a check box to turn on **Smart Zoom** that ***allows you to double-tap*** (tap not click!) the Magic Mouse and ***it zooms just like the trackpad***. It zooms the whole page.

[image: Mouse settings]

I'm not sure about other Mouse brands though. I will update if I try another mouse.

Answer (score 2):

I made [Mac Mouse Fix](https://mousefix.org).

It lets you simulate pinch to zoom by scrolling on your mouse while holding the command key (⌘) on your keyboard, among other cool features.

It's also 100% free, light on system resources, easy-to-use, and fully open source.

[Download](https://mousefix.org) | [GitHub](https://github.com/noah-nuebling/mac-mouse-fix)

Answer (score 0):

My mouse has a scroll wheel as its middle button.
For zoom out or in I can use command with scroll up or down.

I don't remember if that was the default behavior, or I selected it at some past time.

This is set at:

`System Preferences > Accessibility > Zoom`

Comment: This seems to enlarge the entire screen as a bitmap. The difference is that pinch-to-zoom enlarges the web page's text as vectors. So the former makes the text blurry, but the latter does not.

Comment: That's right.  All of these answering and describing macOS wide accessibility zoom feature.  The pinch-to-zoom trackpad operation triggers a zoom-in apps that support it. (like Chrome, Preview, Word, etc)

I haven't yet found a solution on how to emulate this.

Comment: It now seems to be Control, not Command.  But you are right, it zooms the bitmap (the entire window, not the entire screen), not the vector graphics.

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to buy a new mouse from Logitech you can get the desired feature without the apple trackpad. Make sure that you are buying a mouse with 'Logitech Options' support. You can program the actions in multiple ways and it provides many gestures.
https://www.logitech.com/en-ca/product/options

Answer (score -2):

Hold down CTRL and Scroll on your mouse !!

Comment: No, it just scrolls the page. Added: after reading the comment of 'GEdgar'', I found this answer to be the same as his.

Answer (score -2):

It is Option zoom! Not command or control zoom.  It took me a long time to figure this out! I just went from a MacBook to an iMac, and this was a frustrating thing to figure out without a trackpad.  Just hold down the option key and use one finger on your magic mouse moving up and down. This will "pinch zoom" as your MacBook with trackpad does.

I used pinch zoom and now option zoom primarily with docs or iPhoto where I want to see more or fewer photos on the screen and actually change their size I'm viewing. Option zoom does nothing while on a Safari screen for instance, just as pinch zoom didn't.

Comment: Not working for me, I'm using Mojave...

Answer (score -3):

Hold Command and press "+" or "-"